# Unable to overwrite Name ID/NameIdentifier with custom ADFS Claim Rule

Tags: identityserver4, openid, adfs, claims

I've setup IdentityServer4 with external ADFS login. To match the ADFS user with the IdentityServer4 user I need the `EmployeeNumber` attribute from the AD. I added a claim rule (AD FS -> Application Groups -> Web API -> Issuance Transform Rules) which queries the `EmployeeNumber` from the AD and forwards it to `Name ID`/`nameidentifier`:

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
 => issue(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier"), query = ";employeeNumber;{0}", param = c.Value);
```

The EmployeeNumber is a numeric string. But whether or not I add this rule I always get a `nameidentifier` what seems to be a GUID.

I've setup another rule - pretty much the same as the one above - but which passes the EmployeeNumber to `Alternate Login ID`. Now I get the EmployeeNumber as `alternateloginid`. Which would be a workaround. (Code samples for IdentityServer use the `subject` or (as fallback) the `nameidentifier` to identify a user from an external login provider.)

Currently we are still using IdentityServer3. I had setup the ADFS login via WS-Fed. Here I use the same rule as above under AD FS -> Relying Party Trusts -> Edit Claim Issuance Policy. There it works as expected. Also interesting is that I get a lot more claims with the new setup (IdentityServer4/AD FS Application Groups). Maybe it has something to do with the rules under AD FS -> Claims Provider Trusts. there are a couple of "Pass through all ..." rules. I currently don't know if they are here by default or if someone else has set them up for other ADFS clients.

Is there a way to overwrite the `nameidentifier` claim with the `employeeNumber`? Or should I use another claim? If yes what claim would be best to use? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For NameID, I normally use a Transform rule.

Transform EmployeeNumber to NameID and pick the format.

Comment: Thank you! I tried this and other options but the `NameID`/`nameidentifier` always comes as a GUID.

Comment: I suspect that's how idsrv is sending it. NameID is a SAML attribute and idsrv uses OpenID Connect

Comment: I thought the ADFS server is sending this and the idsrv receives it like the other claims from the external login provider. I now use the workaround with `alternateloginid` and use this claim to match the users.

Comment: Good to see you've sorted it. Yes ADFS sends it if you have the correct claims rule. I was wondering what idsrv did with it since it's not a normal OIDC claim.